# Generate Error Sheet from Swift Exception

Tags: swift, macos, exception, error-handling, alert

I'd like to generate an NSAlert-style error sheet from a Swift exception handler. In the past with Objective-C I could simply use `[NSAlert alertWithError:]` Now with Swift and it's own exception handling system in the mix, alerts feel rather clunky:

```
enum Problems: ErrorType {
  case Bad
  case Worse
}

func f() throws {
  throw Problems.Worse
}

func g() {
  let errorMessage: String

  do {
    try f()
  }
  catch Problems.Bad {
    errorMessage = "This was bad"
  }
  catch Problems.Worse {
    errorMessage = "This was even worse"
  }
  catch {
    errorMessage = "This was unexpected"
  }

  guard errorMessage == nil else {
    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText = "Error"
    alert.informativeText = errorMessage
    alert.beginSheetModalForWindow(self, completionHandler: { [unowned self] (returnCode) -> Void in
      if returnCode == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn {
        // Handle the response
      }
    })
  }
```

This feels kludgy and like it doesn't scale well if there are many error conditions that must be checked. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift allows your `ErrorType` to have associated data. This is more or less an exploded version of `userInfo` from `NSError`. If you want convenience, you can write a function to convert a `Problems` enum to `NSError`:

```
enum Problems: ErrorType {
    case Small
    case Bad(message: String?)
    case Worse(message: String?)

    func toNSError() -> NSError {
        var errorMessage = ""

        switch self {
        case .Small:
            errorMessage = "Small error"
        case let .Bad(msg):
            errorMessage = msg ?? "Default bad message"
        case let .Worse(msg):
            errorMessage = msg ?? "Default worse message"
        }

        return NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: errorMessage])
    }
}

func f() throws {
    throw Problems.Worse(message: nil)
}


do {
    try f()
} catch let error as Problems {
    let err = error.toNSError()
    // now display NSAlert with err...
}
```

You can throw an error with `message: nil` to get the default message, or add your own custom message from the local conditions:

```
throw Problems.Bad(message: "I have a bad feeling about this")
```